# CSS using loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have 4 divs and I have to apply the background for every of them according to this array of objects. I know the method css() but didn't know how to loop work.

```
[
  {
    "tix_type": "adult",
    "bg": "gold",
    "tix_pax": 1
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "child",
    "bg": "brown",
    "tix_pax": 0
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "senior",
    "bg": "red",
    "tix_pax": 2
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "disabled",
    "bg": "green",
    "tix_pax": 1
  }
]
```

There is no need for sequence, like 1 div is green, gold and 2 divs are red.

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: loop would have been helpful if your inner objects also had some identifier like DIV ID to identify corresponding DIV's.. you can use jQuery('firstDIvID').css('background': arr[0]['bg']);... so on for other div's

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fag3w0xj/1/

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't provided the HTML structure, This would help you understand the basic logic. you might have to change the part `$('div.styleMe:eq(' + i + ')')` to your respective selctors. Let me know if this helps.

```js
var config = [{
  "tix_type": "adult",
  "bg": "gold",
  "tix_pax": 1
}, {
  "tix_type": "child",
  "bg": "brown",
  "tix_pax": 0
}, {
  "tix_type": "senior",
  "bg": "red",
  "tix_pax": 2
}, {
  "tix_type": "disabled",
  "bg": "green",
  "tix_pax": 1
}]

$.each(config,function(i, v) {
  $('div.styleMe:eq(' + i + ')').css('background-color', v.bg);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="styleMe"></div>
<div class="styleMe"></div>
<div class="styleMe"></div>
<div class="styleMe"></div>
```

Comment: this is wrong, brown should not be shown as the pax is zero, there should be 2 red.

Answer (score 0):

```
var styleArray = [
  {
    "tix_type": "adult",
    "bg": "gold",
    "tix_pax": 1
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "child",
    "bg": "brown",
    "tix_pax": 0
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "senior",
    "bg": "red",
    "tix_pax": 2
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "disabled",
    "bg": "green",
    "tix_pax": 1
  }
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".styled-divs").each(function(index){
       $(this).css("background-color", stylesArray[index].bg );
    });
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="styled-divs"></div>
<div class="styled-divs"></div>
<div class="styled-divs"></div>
<div class="styled-divs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common class(or any selector) to select them all then

```js
var array = [{
  "tix_type": "adult",
  "bg": "gold",
  "tix_pax": 1
}, {
  "tix_type": "child",
  "bg": "brown",
  "tix_pax": 0
}, {
  "tix_type": "senior",
  "bg": "red",
  "tix_pax": 2
}, {
  "tix_type": "disabled",
  "bg": "green",
  "tix_pax": 1
}];

$('.target').css('background-color', function(i) {
  return array[i].bg;
});
```

```css
.target {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: this is wrong, brown should not be shown as the pax is zero, there should be 2 red.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function directly.

```js
var arrayOfObjRef = [
  {
    "tix_type": "adult",
    "bg": "gold",
    "tix_pax": 1
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "child",
    "bg": "brown",
    "tix_pax": 0
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "senior",
    "bg": "red",
    "tix_pax": 2
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "disabled",
    "bg": "green",
    "tix_pax": 1
  }
];

$('div.content').css('background-color', function(i) {
   return arrayOfObjRef[i].bg;
});

console.log('First object bg: ' + arrayOfObjRef[0].bg);
console.log('second object tix_type: ' + arrayOfObjRef[1].tix_type);
console.log('third object tix_pax: ' + arrayOfObjRef[2].tix_pax);
console.log('third object bg: ' + arrayOfObjRef[3].bg);
```

```css
.content {
  height:20px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: this is wrong, brown should not be shown as the pax is zero, there should be 2 red.

Comment: Where did you mention to have the dependency on pax?

Comment: There is no need for sequence, like 1 div is green, gold and 2 divs are red.